# How to log access to a specific folder and changes in its contents?

Tags: command-line, scripts, directory, events, inotify

I need to track folder access time, and want to know what changes are made to it.

How do I trigger those events? Is there a way to run a specific .sh file when the folder is opened?

Comment: search up incron. not sure if it can handle directories, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you need to know the (clock-) time the folder is opened in e.g. *nautilus*, not the *time it takes* to access the folder.

#### Using the window list

You can get the window list from the command `wmctrl -l`, and see if the folder's name occurs in the list. The loop to check would however take at least a split second to notice the folder is opened.

You'd have `wmctrl` to be installed:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

In the example below, the script runs a command when a folder is accessed for the first time, and exits.

*How to use:*

- Paste the script into an empty file
- Save it as `access_time.py`
- Change in the head section of the script `"<command_to_run>"` by your command (between quotes)
- Run it either with the command:

  ```
  python3 </path/to/script> <foldername_without_path>
  ```

  or, if you made it executable:

  ```
  </path/to/access_time.py> <foldername_without_path>
  ```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys
#--- replace "<command_to_run>" with your command (between quotes):
command = "<command_to_run>"
#---
foldername = sys.argv[1]
while True:
    try:
        test = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-l"]).decode("utf-8")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass
    if foldername in test:
        subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
        break
```

#### *Edit*

You can however make it work "all-in-one", so you do not need another script. The script below creates a file in your $HOME directory with the time your folder was accessed.:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import time
home = os.environ["HOME"]
foldername = sys.argv[1]

#--- the path your file is saved to (change if you want to, but use full paths)
path = home
#---

while True:
    try:
        test = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-l"]).decode("utf-8")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass
    if foldername in test:
        with open(path+"/time_data.txt", "a") as out:
            out.write("the folder "+foldername+" was opened "+time.ctime()+"\n")
        break
```

- Use it just like the first option (but obviously you don't need to set the command)
- Place a dot before the filename to make it a hidden file (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to toggle visability):

  If you want that, change:

  ```
  with open(path+"/time_data.txt", "a") as out:
  ```

  into:

  ```
  with open(path+"/.time_data.txt", "a") as out:
  ```

  (Mind the indent!)

#### *Edit 2*

From your comments, and the discussion in chat, I understand that you are actually looking for a tool to log access to a folder (e.g. by nautilus) and changes in the contents of it.
As an extra option, a comprehensive log script that records in two different threads:

- All occasions the folder was accessed by e.g. nautilus, logged in a file `access_log.txt`
- All occasions that the folder's window was closed, also logged in `access_log.txt`
- All files that where either added to (recursively), or removed from the directory, logged into a file `directory_log.txt`

These events are logged in two different files, because the logs have different refresh times. Real-time "recording" of what happens to a large directory with a lot of subdirectories is not something you would want to be done every 5 seconds or so. The consequence is that:

- the *access* log has (as I set it) an accuracy of 0.5 seconds
- the *directory* log (adding/removing files) has an accuracy 10 minutes. Events will be reported within 10 minutes after taking place, with a time stamp accuracy of 10 minutes.

  I tested it on a (network-) directory of ~800 GB. If your directory is much smaller, the *directory* log- cycle can be (much) smaller as well. I tested it for example on a 20 GB directory, with a (directory log) cycle of 10 seconds.

*Example output access_log.txt:*

```
---------------Thu Feb 19 21:01:09 2015---------------
folder opened

---------------Thu Feb 19 21:01:27 2015---------------
folder closed
```

*Example output directory_log.txt:*

```
---------------Thu Feb 19 21:14:24 2015---------------
+ /home/jacob/Afbeeldingen/Downloads/2023.pdf
- /home/jacob/Afbeeldingen/Downloads/History-journal
- /home/jacob/Afbeeldingen/Downloads/google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb
```

#### The script:

- Set it up like the scripts above **with an important difference**:

  - instead of using the folder*name* as an *argument*, set the complete *path*+the foldername in the head of the script (see example in the script)
- The command to run it then is:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/script.py
  ```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import time
import difflib
from threading import Thread
home = os.environ["HOME"]

# The folder to watch:
folder = "/home/jacob/Afbeeldingen"
# the path your log files are saved to (change if you want to, but use full paths):
path = home
#---

for f in os.listdir(path):
    if f.startswith("dr_check_"):
        os.remove(path+"/"+f)

dr_data = path+"/directory_log.txt"
access_data = path+"/access_log.txt"

for f in [dr_data, access_data]:
    if not os.path.exists(f):
        subprocess.Popen(["touch", f])       
foldername = folder.split("/")[-1]

def check_windowlist(foldername):
    while True:
        try:
            if foldername in subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-l"]).decode("utf-8"):
                return "folder opened\n"
            else:
                return "folder closed\n"
            break
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            pass

def check_directory(directory, outfile):
    with open(outfile, "wt") as out:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
            for f in files:
                out.write(root+"/"+f+"\n")

def run_accesscheck():
    while True:
        ch1 = check_windowlist(foldername)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        ch2 = check_windowlist(foldername)
        if ch1 != ch2:
            with open(access_data, "a") as out:
                out.write("-"*15+time.ctime()+"-"*15+"\n"+ch2+"\n")

def run_directorycheck():
    last = 1; outfile_name = "dr_check_"; last_outfile = ""
    while True:
        outfile = path+"/"+outfile_name+str(last)+".txt"
        check_directory(folder, outfile)
        if last != 1:
            changes = []
            diff = difflib.ndiff(
                open(last_outfile).readlines(),
                open(outfile).readlines()
                )
            for item in diff:
                if item.startswith("-") or item.startswith("+"):
                    changes.append(item)
            if len(changes) > 0:
                with open(dr_data, "a") as out:
                    out.write("-"*15+time.ctime()+"-"*15+"\n")
                    for it in sorted(changes):
                        out.write(it)
                    out.write("\n")
            os.remove(last_outfile)       
        last_outfile = outfile; last = last+1
        time.sleep(600)

Thread(target = run_directorycheck).start()
Thread(target = run_accesscheck).start()
```

Comment: When I run this script an error occurs like this,
`~/Documents$ python3 folderWatch.py BackupSSD
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `<some_command>'`

Comment: @tvshajeer The some command is supposed to be replaced by the path to your script, or the command you wish to run.

Comment: @tvshajeer like muru mentioned, the "<some_command>" is not a real command :). What is the command or script you would like to run?.

Comment: @tvshajeer Edited my answer into a "all in one" option, you do not *need* to change anything in this one. Another question: would the script need to record only the first occurrence of accessing the folder, or all / last? would you need (want) to run it on startup?

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm the script should record all access to the folder or folder content changes

Comment: @tvshajeer so *both* changes *and* access via e.g. nautilus? Also if a file is edited?

Comment: I've tried your edited code by `python3 access_time.py BackupSSD`
it doesn't make time_data.txt and ` out.write("the folder "+foldername+" was opened "+time.ctime()+"\n")` was not displayed. it simply executed. no response has displayed.

Comment: @tvshajeer If the targeted folder is open, what is the output of `wmctrl`? It seems to me you are not looking for the time *a folder* is opened, but a *drive* is accessed. That is completely different. A folder appears in the window list. if you need to notify if (any) folder on a drive is accessed requires a totally different approach. Please let me know if that is the case.

Comment: BackupSSD is a folder. Its listed in the output of wmctrl like
`0x026003c4  0 shajeer BackupSSD`

Comment: @tvshajeer if the script ran (and finished) without an error, it noticed the folder was opened and must have created the file. 1. Did you change anything to the script? 2. is the file in the output of `ls ~`?

Comment: `ls ~` lists that text file. what if i need to keep this file in Documents folder. and it records access timestamp can i track folder content changes with this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21252/discussion-between-tvshajeer-and-jacob-vlijm).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Bash instead Python:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
folder=$1
while true;
do
    command=$(wmctrl -l | grep -o "$folder")
    if [[ "$folder" == "$command" ]];
    then
        ./myscript.sh
        break;
    fi
done
```

Edit:

I changed a script so you can run it with the following command:

```
bash folderwatch.sh BackupSSD
```

Also, you can make a script executable so you can use it without sh or bash, because the shell is defined in the first line of the script, for example:

```
chmod u+x folderwatch.sh
./folderwatch.sh BackupSSD
```

Comment: @muru @Panta I ran this sh script using
`~/Documents$ sh folderwatch.sh BackupSSD`
then keep on generating this error
`folderwatch.sh: 6: folderwatch.sh: [[: not found`

Comment: @tvshajeer Instead sh use bash folderwatch.sh. Also foldername replace with a name of folder you want to watch.

Comment: I tried your edited code and it generates an error `folderwatch.sh: line 8: ./myscript.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: @tvshajeer myscript.sh replace with the command you wish to run when the folder is opened.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get incron` to install the "inotify cron" system

http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en

`echo $USER | sudo tee --append /etc/incron.allow` to allow you to play the game.

`icrontab -e` to create an event to watch.  It opens `nano`.

Enter your heart's desire. e.g.,

`/home/nodak/watched_dir  IN_ACCESS /home/nodak/bin/personal.sh`

Save and test.

More information from http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man5/incrontab.5.html

While it is simple, and deceptively so, the syntax for complicated manoeuvres is not quite the same as *regular* bash, c.f., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706194/using-zenity-in-a-root-incron-job-to-display-message-to-currently-logged-in-user